# Function Composition and Expected Value

Tags: probability, expectation, means, random-functions

I was presented with the question

> The function $f(x)$ is equal to $x^2$ and the function $\chi(x)$ gives a random real number from 0 to $x$. Which usually has a greater expected value, $(f \circ \chi)(x)$ or $(\chi \circ f)(x)$ For what values of $x$?

I am almost entirely unexperienced in the field of probability. My approach to this was first to find the expected value of $\chi(x)$, which I think should be
$$\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x x dx=\frac{1}{2}x$$
meaning that the expected value of $(f \circ \chi)(x)$ should be 
$$f(\frac{1}{2}x)=\frac{1}{4}x^2$$
Then I figured that the expected value of $(\chi \circ f)(x)$ would be
$$\frac{1}{x^2}\int_0^{x^2} x dx=\frac{1}{2}x^2$$
Are my methods correct here? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: The second expected value should be $1/2 x^2$. If you think about it, you are finding the average value between $0$ and $x^2$, with each real number in between equally likely.

Comment: Then you can compare and see which is higher for various values for $x$.

Comment: Wait, if the second one should be $\frac{1}{2}x^2$, then the first will always have the higher expected value for positive $x$... is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we take a given number $x_0$, then our random number is a uniform random variable $X$ on $[0,x_0]$. Its probability density function is:
$$ f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x_0} & 0\leq x \leq x_0 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases} $$
If we generate a random number from this distribution, and then square it, our expected value is the expectation of $X^2$:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X^2] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f_{X}(x) \, dx \\
&=\int_0^{x_0} \frac{x^2}{x_0} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{x_0} \int_0^{x_0} x^2 \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{x_0} \cdot \frac{x_0^3}{3} \\
&= \frac{x_0^2}{3}
\end{align*}

---

If we take a given number $x_0$, and square it to get $x_0^2$, our random number is a uniform random variable $Y$ on $[0,x_0^2]$. Its probability density function is:
$$ f_Y(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{x_0^2} & 0\leq x \leq x_0^2 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases} $$
If we generate a random number from this distribution, our expected value is the expectation of $Y$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty x f_Y(x) \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{x_0^2} \frac{x}{x_0^2} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{x_0^2} \int_0^{x_0^2} x \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{x_0^2} \cdot \frac{x_0^4}{2} \\
&= \frac{x_0^2}{2}
\end{align}

---

Hence, we have shown that if we take our $x_0$, generate a random number, and then square it, our expectation is:
$$ \mathbb{E}[(f \circ \chi)(x_0)] = \frac{x_0^2}{3} $$
while on the other hand, if we take our $x_0$, square it, then generate a random number, our expectation is:
$$ \mathbb{E}[(\chi \circ f)(x_0)] = \frac{x_0^2}{2} $$

Comment: So what you're saying in the first one is that the expectation of $X^2$ is not equal to the square of the expectation of $X$?

Comment: Why isn't that true? Forgive me for my ignorance, but I'm very new to this whole field of mathematics, and it just seems to make sense that that would be true.

Comment: That is correct. One counterexample is if you a uniform random variable on [−10,10], then its expectation is 0, so the square of the expectation is 0. However the expectation of the square of this variable cannot be 0, because the square values are nonnegative, and we have positive values.

Comment: Another counterexample is a discrete random variable: the value of the roll of a die. The expectation of the random variable:
$$ 1\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 3\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 4\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 5\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 6\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{2}$$
So the square of the expectation is:
$$ \frac{49}{4} $$
However, the expectation of the square of the random variable is:
$$ 1^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 2^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 3^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 4^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 5^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} + 6^2\cdot\frac{1}{6} = \frac{91}{6} $$